# Networking to get to containers on my local proxmox server from outside

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, home-networking, proxmox

I'm trying to set it up so that I can access one (or multiple) or my proxmox containers from the outside internet. Here's what I need help understanding:

1. I don't have a static IP address at my house (Google Fiber won't give me one unless I'm a business). I'm betting that I should DynamicDNS in some fashion to always point my websites at my servers. I use Namecheap, and they have a way of doing that. Should I use that or go with something like Dyno?
2. To manage my local networking, do I need to buy a NIC, install pfSense in a VM in proxmox, and use that instead of my GFiber router they gave me, or should I just buy new router and use that instead of my GFiber one? The reason I ask is that I'm assuming I need to configure some NAT settings at the router level to make this work, right? I can't find any NAT settings or anything similar in my current GFiber router's Advanced Settings.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, Namecheap's [dynamic DNS](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/36/11/how-do-i-start-using-dynamic-dns/) is fine for what you want to do.
2. None of that - you want to look for port forwarding settings, not NAT: https://support.google.com/fiber/answer/4643957

Comment: Okay, after a bit more googling that makes sense now, but does that mean I'm not able to run multiple containers and expose all of them to the internet simultaneously? I guess I would have to either have users put in the port manually or run a reverse proxy that forwards traffic to the right port, which then gets forwarded to the right container. ugh.

Comment: @TylerCheek That's a bit of a different question, but yes. Your ISP connection only has one public IP address, so separate listening services must run on separate ports. And yes, you can condense them into one listener with something like a proxy that understands whatever you plan to separate them on, like hostname or url.

Comment: Your users already have to "manually" put in whatever you send them. Most services allow adding the port right to the hostname like server.domain.com:1234, which works for http/ssh/sql for example, so it's no different to users in most cases